How to add the shadow to drawn curve in Jetpack Compose?
How can I add a shadow that follows the drawn bottom curve using Jetpack Compose? (See the image below)
I'm not asking about how to draw the curve itself - just whether there’s any way to add a shadow to a custom-drawn curve Example that I have drawn somehow using `drawPath()
val path = Path().apply {
    // some function to draw the curve
}

drawPath(
    path = path,
    color = Color.Gray,
    style = Stroke(width = 3.dp.toPx())
)

Is there any way to make shadow for them?


So, do you want to show the shadow inside a Canvas, or do you want to apply the shadow on a Card whose shape is clipped to match the path? These are two different things that require different answers.

In this question's scope, I just want to apply the shadow on the curve (in the middle bottom) drawn by Canvas

If you have the Path() or functions to create Path you can create a Shape with GenericShape. Then apply this Shape to background, border, clip or shadow as you like.
   val shape: Shape = remember {
        GenericShape { size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection ->

          // some function to draw the curve
        }
    }

You can add another path with addPath(externalPath) if Path comes from external library or draw with Path functions inside builder.
Then Modifier.shadow(2.dp, shape).background(Color.White) to draw shadow and background.
You can also check M3 composables section of this answer to see how shape is created from another 2 shapes and applied to Composables.
